# Error in is.single.string(object) : argument "object" is missing, with no default

Tags: r

I want to parse the `AAChange.refGene` column and then use biomaRt R package to extract information. My code is raising `Error in is.single.string(object) :  argument "object" is missing, with no default` even though the `getSequence` function is meant to accept multiple arguments.

```
library(tidyr)

variant_calls = read.delim("variant_calls.txt")
info = tidyr::separate(variant_calls["AAChange.refGene"], AAChange.refGene, c("Refseq ID", "cDNA level change", "Protein level change"), ":")
df = cbind(variant_calls["Gene.refGene"],info) 

library(biomaRt)
ensembl <- useMart(biomart="ENSEMBL_MART_ENSEMBL", dataset="hsapiens_gene_ensembl", host="https://grch37.ensembl.org", path="/biomart/martservice")

pep <- vector()
for(i in 1:length(df$`Refseq ID`)){
  temp <- getSequence(id=df$`Refseq ID`[i],type='refseq_mrna',seqType='peptide', mart=ensembl)
  temp <- sapply(temp$peptide, nchar)
  temp <- sort(temp, decreasing = TRUE)
  temp <- names(temp[1])
  pep[i] <- temp
}
df$Sequence <- pep
```

Traceback:

```
Error in is.single.string(object) : 
  argument "object" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and found out (using ?getSequence) that it was a conflict between packages (classic R), specifically *biomart and* *seqinr* which is used to handle fasta format thus probably used together often.

My solution consisted in calling the function like this:

`biomaRt::getSequence()`